# Difference between Mavic Deemax Ultimate 2011 and latest version

Tags: wheels, downhill

Have an offer to get Mavic Deemax Ultimates from 2011 for my downhill bike. They cost half as much as the current model.
Can anyone tell me what the changes are compared to the current models?

Comment: This is a shopping question and is likely to be closed as it isn't really useful for the community at large (shopping questions don't fit the SE format well). You should look at the data sheets.

Comment: @Batman I'm not sure this is really a shopping question in that it's not asking for product recommendations. Rather, it's asking how a product has changed over time. The OP wants to use that info in a shopping decision, but it's not really part of the question. It may not be super useful for the community at large, but [we don't have a "too localized" closure anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons). My vote is leave open.

Comment: I could rephrase the question like this: Can anyone tell me the difference between 2011 and 2014 Mavic Deemax Ultimate. I can't find specs for the old models and also there might be changes that are not visible by pure technical terms.

Comment: @JanDetlefsen did you ever answer this question ?